# In Corda, how can a node that isn't a participant store a state in its vault?

Tags: corda

In Corda, nodes only store states for which they are one of the `participants` (unless the state is an `OwnableState`, in which case they only store it if they are the `owner`).

How can I override this behaviour and get a node to store a state for which they are not a participant?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of choosing to record only states in which they are one of the `participants`, nodes can choose to record every state in a transaction they receive. I've written out an example below. You can also take a look at the Observable States CorDapp implementing this pattern [here](https://github.com/corda/samples).

**Sending the transaction**

First, a node who has the transaction that contains the states in question needs to send the transaction to the counterparty(s) who want to record it but who are not `participants`. Here is how we'd define a `BrodcastTransactionFlow` to do this:

```
@InitiatingFlow
class BroadcastTransaction(
    val stx: SignedTransaction, 
    val counterparty: Party) : FlowLogic<Unit>() {

    @Suspendable
    override fun call() {
        val session = initiateFlow(counterparty)
        subFlow(SendTransactionFlow(session, stx))
    }
}
```

**Receiving the transaction and storing all the states**

The counterparty(s) would have to register a responder flow that records all the states in the transaction. Here is how we'd define a `RecordTransactionAsObserver` to do this:

```
@InitiatedBy(BroadcastTransaction::class)
class RecordTransactionAsObserver(val otherSession: FlowSession) : FlowLogic<Unit>() {

    @Suspendable
    override fun call() {
        val flow = ReceiveTransactionFlow(
                otherSideSession = otherSession,
                checkSufficientSignatures = true,
                // We are recording all the states, 
                // and not just the ones where we are participants.
                statesToRecord = StatesToRecord.ALL_VISIBLE
        )

        subFlow(flow)
    }
}
```